# A two column and three column even and responsive Isotope grid

Tags: jquery, css

Can anyone help me perfect a grid that has three columns in one row and two columns in the other. I have a js fiddle to demonstrate what I'm saying. I want the gaps between the grids to be equal to one another and also the length of the entire row making it even on all sizes. Right now, the three column is not even with the two columns. Even the gaps is not even.

This is my code for the grids:

```
.home.w5 { width: 48.879%; }
.home.w2 { width: 32.0%; }
```

[link to JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vanduzled/4HYSj/)

Preview of the image I want to achieve:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean when you say `the three column is not even with the two columns`, Can you draw a quick picture using Paint for example to show us what you want to be displayed ?

Comment: @singe31 I think what they mean is that the total width of the 2 column section is wider than the 3 column section. See this jsfiddle which has all the necessary libraries included http://jsfiddle.net/4HYSj/2/

Comment: @singe31 I added a photo on my question. I want the edge of the column to be inline (or aligned) with the other column. I can't seem to achieve it because it seems like it's always short of few pixels OR too much that the three columns fall off the other row.

Comment: Changing in the css `.home-grid-sizer` from `width:1%` to `width:5.022%` seems to work pretty good to me. http://jsfiddle.net/fgHH7/ I have no idea why it's working though because this parameter should be used to specify the width of a column, right ?

Comment: Thanks @singe31 for figuring it out. Making the .w2 "32.12%" makes it more precise and even. I really don't know how to compute this grid as I am no mathematician. But this should do by now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply you're missing the imagesLoaded library. To use that functionality you need to include it. You can find it here: http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/imagesloaded.pkgd.js

So you'd just need to include in your code something like:

```
<script src="http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/imagesloaded.pkgd.js"></script>
```

See jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4HYSj/2/

Comment: I have the imagesloaded plugin on my actual work but that doesn't help with the grids not being even. if you see the fiddle, the bottom grid has three columns and it's not even with the two column on top. That is the problem I'm having and it doesn't have anything to do with images.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed your problem was the obvious gaps in your jsfiddle.